# Alternate solution for RSA security ID

Tags: java, servlets, rsa

Do we have any alternate solution to replace RSA Security ID for the web-application developed in JAVA-Servlet?

More Details:

The Current application uses RSA Security ID for authentication. Now we are planning to replace "RSA Security ID" technology.

Is there any way to implement this authentication? (Simply db/ldap password are not recommended)

Comment: Your authentication domain requires someone to enter a value from a SecurID token? Sure, talk to whoever administers the security realm. Or are you talking about some other RSA "Security ID"? You'll get much better answers if you don't expect people to read your mind.

Comment: OK, so how do you implement authentication now? Do you use a login servlet/JSP, or do you use a web-server plugin?

Comment: And I guess the real question: are you asking people to tell you alternatives to RSA SecurID (it's a trademarked product, simply calling it "security ID" is incorrect)? That's very different than asking how to implement such a change.

Comment: to replace the token, make an iphone or blackberry app. make sure its synced with your servers.  otherwise your talking about regular passwords, or manufacturing your own hardware (bloomberg does this).  i dont know of any competitors in that arena.

Comment: Having app in mobile phones to generate password and to sync with the web application is an Excellent alternate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generally trying to replace an existing 2 Factor Authentication (2FA) system.

There are quite a few options available.  The compromises are between the cost, convenience and security.  The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-factor_authentication) on the topic gives a good run down of the options.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely. But your question, as phrased, does not have a simple answer. Grab the closest [CISSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certified_Information_Systems_Security_Professional) and ask him/her to explain your options.